# Slices: Trouble appending to a slice in a struct

Tags: arrays, go, slice

So, I'm trying to get used to Go! and I've come up to a problem where I try making a new data type  "RandomType" which contains a slice.

```
package main

type RandomType struct {
    RandomSlice []int
}

func main() {
    r := new(RandomType)
    r.RandomSlice = make([]int, 0)
    append(r.RandomSlice, 5)
}
```

This bit of code yields an error:

```
append(r.RandomSlice, 5) not used
```

However for instance if I try with

```
type RandomType struct {
    RandomInt int
}

func main() {
    r := new(RandomType)
    r.RandomInt = 5
}
```

this works fine.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`append` doesn't change the slice you provide but builds a new one.

You must use the returned slice :

```
 r.RandomSlice = append(r.RandomSlice, 5)
```

More details about append [in Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#append) and [in the Go blog](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

Comment: Sometimes, not always, `append` allocates a new slice. "If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values, `append` allocates a new, sufficiently large slice that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Thus, the returned slice may refer to a different underlying array."

Comment: @peterSO Yes, but I'm unsure of why you make this remark : the underlying array may be the same but the slice always is different and it's an error not to use the returned value of append (which is fine as it probably avoids many bugs).

Comment: `append` is a recent construct, not something which was designed at the same time than arrays and slices, that might be why it feels a little unnatural.